# Push view controller into modal view controller view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I'm trying to get working a simple operation. At least it seems simple. Ok, what I'd like to do is to push a view (with push view controller) from a view that has been pushed with modal view controller.

View1 --(push using modal view controller)-->View2--(push using push view controller)--View3.

Rigth now, i'm doing tests so i'm using a button to start the action. Here's the code I use to push from View2 to view 3:

```
//view2.h
UIToolbar *bar;
UIBarButtonItem *button;
UIToolbar *toolbar;

}

- (IBAction)demissModal:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)goView3:(id)sender;

@end

//view2.m
- (IBAction)goView3:(id)sender{

View3 *view_3 = [[View3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View3" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view_3 animated:YES];

}
```

This is the same code I use to push View1 to View2, and it works. But when pushing View2 to View3, it's not working. Any idea of why happens that? Thanks!

Comment: you need to push the view controller on the active controller. See if this works [self pushViewController:view_3 animated:YES];

Answer (score 11, accepted):

View Controllers aren't actually 'modal' or 'push' view controllers. Modal or Push describe a transition between view controllers (called segues if you're using storyboards).

What I think you're asking is how to modally present a view controller, and then push another controller. The trick is when you modally present view controller #1, to actually present a navigation controller with its root view controller set as view controller #1.

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [MyViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];

// Presuming a view controller is asking for the modal transition in the first place.
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
// Now in myViewController, call [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

This is what it looks like using storyboards:
[image]

Comment: Ok this is working but not very well. When the second view is diplayed with modal transition, then I saw the button that has to be pressed to change to View3. If i press the button once, it displays the same view with modal transition, and if I press another view, it shows the same with an strange transition. I don't know why happens that.

Comment: What code is being run when you press the button that should cause the push? It should be something like `[self.navigationController pushViewController:<#UIViewController#> animated:YES];`

Comment: Here's the code I'm using: View *myViewController = [[View2 alloc] init];
    
    View3 *descripcio = [[View3 alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:View2];
   
   [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:View3 animated:YES];

Comment: Ah ok. What is `View` a subclass of? It should be a subclass of `UIViewController`. Additionally, the class which myViewController is an instance of should have its memory allocated by that class. Here's how you would do it with blank view controllers:

`UIViewController *redViewController = [UIViewController alloc] init];`
`redViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`
`UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:redViewController];`
`[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: In the example above, whatever `UIViewController` subclass is in the place of the redViewController, there should be a button. If you add that button in code, use `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` to add a method. In that method, use the `self.navigationController pushViewController:animated:` method.

Comment: With the code you last write, It works but it uses modal transitions to display the redViewController. For now i'm using a button to make code simpler, but the final code will use a table. I'll search more but previous searches were useless. At now i'm not using storyboards, but this couldn't be the problem no? Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ok, I managed to get it working. I found an interesting post here: [Post](http://hwww.kickasslabs.com/2009/07/03/uinavigationcontroller-tricks) It helped me to solve the problem. Anyway, thanks for all the help I received!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view_3 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not sure where that gegant_se is coming from.

Second of all, if you're pushing view2 from view1 the same way you're pushing view3 from view2, you're not using a modal.

Whenever you use a navigation controller to push a view controller, that view controller that was just pushed has a reference to the navigation controller, through the navigationController property. Try this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view_3 animated:YES];
```

Comment: Sorry about that gegant_se. It was just a test and I forgot to change it.

Answer (score 0):

try this code AlarmList is view name .

AlarmListScreen *loscr=[[AlarmListScreen alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:loscr animated:YES];

```
[loscr release];
```